# Salvando arquivos em txt com Android Studio

Tags: android, arquivo

Estou com problemas para salvar o nome digitado pelo usuário em um arquivo txt.

Quando eu aperto salvar, diz que foi criado, mas eu não consigo ler.

Context fileContext;

```
public BancoDeDados(Context fileContext) {
    this.fileContext = fileContext;
}

public void gravar(String nome) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream os = fileContext.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("bdNome.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        os.write(nome.getBytes());
        os.close();
        System.out.println("Salvou");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Deu erro");
    }
}
```

Comment: E onde está seu método de leitura? O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Já chegou as permissões?!

Answer (score 1):

Gente, aqui está a resposta. 
Eu consegui.

```
public void gravar ( String data ) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = fileContext.openFileOutput ( "arquivo.txt" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE ) ;
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter ( fOut ) ;
            osw.write ( data ) ;
            osw.flush ( ) ;
            osw.close ( ) ;
            System.out.println("ok");
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( ) ;
            System.out.println("Deu erro");
        }
    }

public String ler ( ) {
    StringBuffer datax = new StringBuffer("");
    try {
        FileInputStream fIn = fileContext.openFileInput ( "arquivo.txt" ) ;
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader ( fIn ) ;
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader ( isr ) ;

        String readString = buffreader.readLine ( ) ;
        while ( readString != null ) {
            datax.append(readString);
            readString = buffreader.readLine ( ) ;
        }

        isr.close ( ) ;
        System.out.println("ok");
    } catch ( IOException ioe ) {
        System.out.println("Deu erro");
        ioe.printStackTrace ( ) ;
    }
    return datax.toString() ;
}
```